# How shall SQL statement be designed to also caluculate number of devices?

Tags: exchangewebservices, logparser

How shall I design sql statement to also calculate the number of devices within every User-Agent ID?

I work in MS Log Parser Studio (LOGPARSER), working on programming different query Exchange logs (IIS W3C LOG) to compile statistics of mobile devices.

This is the query:

```
SELECT TO_STRING(To_timestamp(date, time), 'MM-dd-yyyy') as Day, cs(user-agent) as
UserAgent /* Count(MyDeviceId as DeviceId) as NrOfSameDevice 
USING
EXTRACT_VALUE(cs-uri-query,'DeviceId') as MyDeviceId */
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' 
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync%'
GROUP BY Day, UserAgent
ORDER BY Day
```

Result of this query is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to calculate the number of *distinct* devices for each *Day, UserAgent* pair.

This is normally done with a COUNT(DISTINCT) or a nested query, but since LogParser does not support neither (COUNT(DISTINCT) is not supported with GROUP BY), you'll have to break the query in two:

1. The first query selects the distinct combinations of Day, UserAgent, and DeviceId:

   SELECT DISTINCT TO_STRING(To_timestamp(date, time), 'MM-dd-yyyy') as Day, cs(user-agent) as
   UserAgent, EXTRACT_VALUE(cs-uri-query,'DeviceId') as MyDeviceId 
   INTO TmpOutput.csv
   FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
2. The second query parses the result of the first one grouping by the first two fields:

   SELECT Day, UserAgent, COUNT(*)
   FROM TmpOutput.csv
   GROUP BY Day, UserAgent
   ORDER BY Day

Make sure that the first command is configured to also output headers into TmpOutput.csv.